# Goblet Squats vs. Regular Squats

Tags: weightlifting, muscle, squats

I'm tempted to include Goblet Squats into my workout routine, because they seem easy to execute (you only need a single Dumbbell) and look fun.

**Now, in terms of muscle activation, where are (if any) the differences between a Goblet Squat and regular Squats** (let's say, front and back loaded ones). I was able to find a lot of material comparing the Front and Back Loaded Squat with each other, but little to no information about the Goblet Squat.

Other than "the Goblet Squat is good for beginners", there either doesn't seem to be much information or I'm not researching the right way.

Comment: They are fun!  Which is a good enough reason to do them in my books.

Comment: @Roger That's right! I'll definitly include them in my routine somewhere, also because I like to switch things up every few months. Still was wondering about the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goblet squats are pretty much identical to a front squat, except that they are limited in the amount of weight that they can be loaded with.

That is, there will likely* be more loading of the quadriceps and less loading of the glutes compared to a low-bar back squat of the same weight, and more loading of the thoracic spine and less of the lumbar spine compared with any kind of back squat.

* I say likely, because it is actually much more possible to do a more hip-dominant goblet squat, where there is significant forward lean of the torso and the knees do not move very far forwards, than it is a hip-dominant front squat. Such a goblet squat would use less quads, but still have the increased thoracic loading. (In a barbell front squat, the movement cannot be performed with a significant forward lean of the torso, as one would normally use in a low-bar back squat, as the hands would not be able to hold the barbell in this position.)